# Python Requests Go to Link and Download

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to do the following in an automated fashion:

1. Go to this link: https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Enrollment-by-Contract-Plan-State-County-DL.xml
2. Follow the link at the very bottom of the page (ending with the current year and month (i.e. http://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Enrollment-by-Contract-Plan-State-County-Items/Monthly-Enrollment-by-CPSC-2016-04.html)
3. At the next page, download the zip file from the top link under "downloads":
   Monthly Enrollment by CPSC - April 2016 [ZIP, 20MB]

So far, I have the following to get the current year and month, but I need help with the rest...

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
Day = datetime.now().day
Month = datetime.now().month
Year = datetime.now().year
m=calendar.month_name[Month]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need an XML parser to extract the link from the XML feed and the HTML parser to extract the link to the zip file. For that, here we'll use [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) and [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) respectively. Working implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html


date_part = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m")
with requests.Session() as session:
    # get the XML feed and extract the link
    response = session.get("https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Enrollment-by-Contract-Plan-State-County-DL.xml")
    root = etree.fromstring(response.content)
    link = root.xpath("//item/link[contains(., '-%s.html')]/text()" % date_part)[0]

    # follow the link and extract the link to the zip file
    response = session.get(link)
    root = html.fromstring(response.content)
    zip_link = root.xpath("//a[@type='application/zip']/@href")[0]
    link = urljoin(link, zip_link)

    # download zip
    urlretrieve(link, filename="my.zip")
```

Comment: Hello. I'm using Anaconda with Python 3.5 and I got this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'urlretrieve'   I tried pip install urllib but it's already installed. Have you ever run into this?

Comment: @DanceParty2 sorry, fixed the import, please recheck.

Comment: If you never worked with Python and the web, I suggest you to try out Selenium! With it, you can really see what is going on and solve very complicated tasks, too. Also it shares some of the syntax with lxml and you'll get an understanding of HTML and how webpages are parsed. To get you started you can visit the [Selenium Homepage](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and also get their Firefox-Addon.

Comment: @Krazor that's always an option, but the question is python-requests specific judging by the title and the tags. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That is why this is a comment and not an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks @alecxe...For some reason I can't figure out where the zip file was saved. I looked in my home directory but didnt' see it.

Comment: Also thanks @Krazor for the Selenium reference, I'll definitely check it out. I'm wondering which is the best approach for getting data when a login and password are required (and a few menu clicks) but this seems like a good idea.

Comment: @DanceParty2 you can provide a `filename` argument and set a custom path..I've updated the code in the answer - saving the zip file into the `my.zip` file in the current directory. Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks!

Comment: That really depends on your usecase. For efficiency you *definitely* want to go for Urllib or any other module that provides similar functionality. The problem with these modules is that they don't provide the browser-functions that many webpages depend on. By using a headless browser such as Selenium you can load addons, run Javascript or other dynamic elements with ease and check their runtime state in the DOM. Also it provides a new layer for you as the Dev to toy with your code. So you get a neat little console application that acts as a scriptable browser. Choose for yourself.